# A quick introduction to Complex Ginzburg-Landau Equation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, complex-systems

The complex Ginzburg-Landau equation is given as follows:
$$
\partial_{t} A=A+(1+i b) \Delta A-(1+i c)|A|^{2} A.
$$

For some reasons, I need to quickly understand what the parameters in the equation mean and to have a general idea what the equation does. And I hope to find some newcomer-friendly introductions to this topic, which should be oriented to complex systems. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Original Ginzburg-Landau model describing superconductors is not time dependent, and it is not looks like it shown in your post. The time dependent model has been propose by  G.M.  Eliashberg and L.P.  Gor’kov in the paper   "Generalization  of  Ginzburg-Landau  equations for non-stationary problems in the case of alloys with paramagnetic impurities". J. Exptl. Theoret. Phys. (U.S.S.R.), 27, 1968.

Comment: For your request see this paper http://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2009/Spring/physics221a/REFERENCES/complex_gle.pdf

Comment: Could you please tell me the preliminaries to read this paper without obstacles?

Comment: What kind of obstacles you experienced to read?

Comment: For example, I don't know what is "second-order
phase transitions"...

Comment: What for do you study this equation? About phase transition classification read subsection "Modern classifications" on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition

Comment: I study it for doing research in (numerical) dynamic systems. Anyway thanks a lot for your help!